# Use JCodeModel to generate toString() method

Tags: java, tostring, jcodemodel

I am attempting to generate Java Value Objects using `com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel`.

I have managed to generate `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods but I am struggling with `toString()`;

I require the following `toString()` implementation

```
return "ClassName [field1 = " + field1 + ", field2 = " + field2 ... ", fieldN = " + fieldN + "]";
```

How do I create a `JCodeModel` `JExpression` that contains `JExpr.lit(field1.name())` concatenated with `JExpr.ref(fieldVar.name())`?

All i've managed to do is generate a string literal resembling:-

```
return "ClassName [field1 =  field1 + field2 = field2 ... fieldN = + fieldN + ]";
```

Heres my skeleton method so far:-

```
final Map<String, JFieldVar> fields = jclass.fields();
final JMethod toString = jclass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, String.class, "toString");
final Set<String> excludes = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(ruleFactory.getGenerationConfig().getToStringExcludes()));

final JBlock body = toString.body();

for (JFieldVar fieldVar : fields.values()) {
    if (excludes.contains(fieldVar.name()) || ((fieldVar.mods().getValue() & JMod.STATIC) == JMod.STATIC)) {
        continue;
    }

    ??????????????

}

body._return(?????????);

toString.annotate(Override.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is likely that you can combine multiple `JExpression` objects with the `+` operator by using the `JExpression#plus` method.

Here is an example that contains the definition of a simple example class, and a method to generically generate the `toString` method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter;
import com.sun.codemodel.JBlock;
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
import com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass;
import com.sun.codemodel.JExpr;
import com.sun.codemodel.JExpression;
import com.sun.codemodel.JFieldVar;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMethod;
import com.sun.codemodel.JMod;
import com.sun.codemodel.writer.SingleStreamCodeWriter;

public class CodeModelToStringTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
        JDefinedClass definedClass = codeModel._class("com.example.Example");

        definedClass.field(JMod.PUBLIC, String.class, "exampleString");
        definedClass.field(JMod.PROTECTED, int.class, "exampleInt");
        definedClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, float.class, "exampleFloat");

        definedClass.field(JMod.PRIVATE, String.class, "excludedString");
        definedClass.field(JMod.STATIC, String.class, "staticString");

        createToStringMethod(definedClass, Arrays.asList("excludedString"));

        CodeWriter codeWriter = new SingleStreamCodeWriter(System.out);
        codeModel.build(codeWriter);
    }

    private static void createToStringMethod(
        JDefinedClass definedClass,
        Collection<String> excludedFieldNames)
    {
        Map<String, JFieldVar> fields = definedClass.fields();
        JMethod toString =
            definedClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, String.class, "toString");
        toString.annotate(Override.class);

        JBlock body = toString.body();

        JExpression expression = JExpr.lit(definedClass.name() + " [");

        boolean first = true;
        for (JFieldVar fieldVar : fields.values())
        {
            if ((fieldVar.mods().getValue() & JMod.STATIC) == JMod.STATIC)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (excludedFieldNames.contains(fieldVar.name()))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (!first)
            {
                expression = expression.plus(JExpr.lit(", "));
            }
            expression = expression.plus(JExpr.lit(fieldVar.name()+" = "));
            expression = expression.plus(JExpr.ref(fieldVar.name()));
            first = false;
        }
        expression = expression.plus(JExpr.lit("]"));

        body._return(expression);


    }
}
```

The generated class with the `toString` method is shown here:

```
package com.example;


public class Example {

    public String exampleString;
    protected int exampleInt;
    private float exampleFloat;
    private String excludedString;
    static String staticString;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ((((((((("Example ["+"exampleString = ")+ exampleString)+", ")+"exampleInt = ")+ exampleInt)+", ")+"exampleFloat = ")+ exampleFloat)+"]");
    }

}
```

The fact that CodeModel inserts `(` brackets `)` around each binary operation causes the code to not look so pretty. But it's understandable: Otherwise, they would have to take operator precedences into account, and the usage and the code generation itself would likely be **far** harder.

However, the result of this `toString` method will be

```
Example [exampleString = null, exampleInt = 0, exampleFloat = 0.0]
```

which should be what you expected, based on your examples.

Comment: thanks very much for taking the time to address my issue. The only downside is the excessive brackets that CodeModel inserts.

Comment: @Hector This has been asked for in https://stackoverflow.com/q/12961769/3182664 , but I think that it's rather an "aesthetical" (and not so much a technical) issue.